# Requirements collecting

Tags: python, bigdata

How would gather requirements for a data science project? How do you convince stakeholders that whatever you develop is going to benefit them? How to build trust to make use of data science for the business operations?

Answer (score 0):

An answer to the third question: "How to build trust to make use of data science for the business operations?"

It heavily depends on the type and structure of data that you want to get access and the application that you want to provide.

For example, if data owner has a concern about the privacy of its users, and you just want to execute some statistical queries over their data, you should design and propose a privacy-preserving method for accessing to their data. There are some techniques like [Differential Privacy (or Randomized Response)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy) which provide a well-defined privacy guarantee for data owner.

Answer (score 0):

Ask a lot of questions.

For example:

- "What is in your biggest pain point?"
- "What do you want to automate to make your job easier?"
- "What data do you have?"

Then listen to the answers. Build things that are useful. Teach people how to use the new systems.